# Creating duplicate records into SQLite Database while updating existing Record

Tags: android, sqlite

In my program i am using SQLite database to store data, and also allowing user to update existing record as well.

my code helps me to update existing record, but its creating duplicate entry with updated record, for an example: if update any record 7 times so its creating 7 entries for the same updated record with updated data.

**using below lines of code in Activity :-**

```
           saveStatus = myDb.UpdateData(
                editImage.getText().toString(),
                editPersonName.getText().toString());
```

**database class code :-**

```
public long UpdateData(String strImageName, String strPersonName){
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            SQLiteDatabase db;
            db = this.getWritableDatabase(); // Write Data

            ContentValues Val = new ContentValues();
            Val.put("ImageName", strImageName);
            Val.put("PersonName", strPersonName);

            long rows = db.update(TABLE_MEMBER, Val, "ImageName=?",
                    new String[] { String.valueOf(strImageName) });

            db.close();
            return rows; // return rows updated.

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return -1;
        }   
    }
```

**whole code:**

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Create Table Name
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MEMBER + 
                  "(ImageName VARCHAR(100)," +
                  " PersonName VARCHAR(100));");

        Log.d("CREATE TABLE","Create Table Successfully - classs");
    }

    // Insert Data
    public long InsertData(String strImageName, String strPersonName) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         try {
            SQLiteDatabase db;
            db = this.getWritableDatabase(); // Write Data

            ContentValues Val = new ContentValues();
            Val.put("ImageName", strImageName); 
            Val.put("PersonName", strPersonName);

            long rows = db.insert(TABLE_MEMBER, null, Val);

            db.close();
            return rows; // return rows inserted.

         } catch (Exception e) {
            return -1;
         }
    }

    // Update Data
    public long UpdateData(String strImageName, String strPersonName){
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            SQLiteDatabase db;
            db = this.getWritableDatabase(); // Write Data

            ContentValues Val = new ContentValues();
            Val.put("ImageName", strImageName);
            Val.put("PersonName", strPersonName);

            long rows = db.update(TABLE_MEMBER, Val, "ImageName=?",
                    new String[] { String.valueOf(strImageName) });

            db.close();
            return rows; // return rows updated.

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return -1;
        }   
    }

    // Fetch data
    public String[] SelectData(String strImageName) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         try {
            String arrData[] = null;    

             SQLiteDatabase db;
             db = this.getReadableDatabase(); // Read Data

             Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_MEMBER, new String[] { "*" }, 
                        "ImageName=?",
                        new String[] { String.valueOf(strImageName) }, null, null, null, null);

                if(cursor != null)
                {
                    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        arrData = new String[cursor.getColumnCount()];

                        arrData[0] = cursor.getString(0);
                        arrData[1] = cursor.getString(1);
                    }
                }
                cursor.close();
                db.close();
                return arrData;

         } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
         }
    }

    // Check for data(s) using ImageName field
    public boolean Exists(String strImageName) {
           SQLiteDatabase db;
           db = this.getReadableDatabase(); // Read Data
           Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select 1 from DataTable where ImageName= ?", 
                new String[] { strImageName });
           boolean exists = (cursor.getCount() > 0);
           cursor.close();
           return exists;
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_MEMBER);
        // Re Create on method  onCreate
        onCreate(db);
    }
```

Comment: Why do you do `String.valueOf(strImageName)`? The `strImageName` is already a String. It's also a good idea to add `UNIQUE` constraint to `ImageName` column, since you don't want duplicates in this column, right? As for why `update()` creates duplicates for you - it seems like your "where clause" doesn't match your original row correctly. Have you tried to execute SELECT-WHERE on your database from some SQLite managing software?

Comment: 1 suggestion, to check your SQLite query, use SQLiteManager application. Install it and import your SQL database. Check if your query is correct. It's easier to modify query in that app, rather than compiling and running code.